# Jquery: force cursor into next input field gracefully?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 input fields next to eachother.

I'm trying to force the user to enter 1 character per input field and as soon as they entered 1 character, they need to enter the next character into the next field until the inputs finish.

However my current code is al over the place and I can't figure out what I need to do to achieve this.

This is my code:

https://jsfiddle.net/ej9tvosj/

```
$('.inps').keydown(function (event) {
    // check for hyphen
var myLength = $(this).val().length;

if(myLength ==0){
$(this).next('.inps').focus();
}


});
```

if you enter something in the first one, it will jump into the next field but it will get messed up there after.

Could someone please advice on this issue?

Comment: You need to use `keypress` instead of `keydown`

Comment: Check my answer. This is what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to try `on input` listener to detect change in input instead of `keyup` since you need to ensure that a character is entered before changing focus.

```js
$(document).on('input', '.inps', function (event) {
   // check for hyphen
 var myLength = $(this).val().trim().length;
  if(myLength ==1){
    $(this).next('.inps').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inps" >
<input type="text" class="inps" >
<input type="text" class="inps" >
<input type="text" class="inps" >
```

Comment: Boom... perfection

Comment: @AKA, It does not work the same. re-test both codes and you'll see the difference.

Comment: @AKA, your code works but not in the case for validating the input. Since your code need second `keydown` for foucs of next `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the `myLength` value with `1` like in the code snippet below:

```js
$('.inps').keydown(function (event) {
    // check for hyphen
var myLength = $(this).val().length;

if(myLength ==1){
$(this).next('.inps').focus();
}


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="inps" >
<input type="text" class="inps" >
<input type="text" class="inps" >
<input type="text" class="inps" >
```

Comment: I'm trying to jump to the next field as soon as there is 1 character in the field. So for example, I enter A in the first field and then it will jump to the next field.

Comment: This is what it does. Click on 'Run Code Snippet' above and see.